# Oracle object relational DB: Access columns of referenced rows

Tags: sql, oracle, view, object-relational-model

I have some tables and need to create object views on top of them.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
Nr NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR2(15)); 

CREATE TABLE Professor (
Nr NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
HabilThema VARCHAR2(30));
```

I also created types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person_Typ AS OBJECT(
    Nr INTEGER,
    Name VARCHAR2(15)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Professor_Typ AS OBJECT(
    Nr INTEGER,
    Habilthema VARCHAR2(30),
    Person REF Person_Typ
);
```

As you can see there is a reference from a professor row to a person row. The view of the professors now should also include the columns of the person. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW People OF Person_Typ
    WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER(Nr) AS
        SELECT p.Nr, p.Name FROM Person p;

CREATE VIEW Professors OF Professor_Typ
    WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER(Nr) AS 
        SELECT p.Nr, p.Habilthema, p.Person.Name, MAKE_REF(People,p.Nr) FROM Professor p;
                                             ^
                                             |_ Name of professor from Person table
```

But this does not work:

```
"P"."PERSON"."NAME" invalid identifier
```

Can this even be achieved by an object view? How?

Comment: You can't do that.  Need to do a join with the professor table.

Comment: Ah, okay. I also just noticed I misread the specification by the way. May I accept your comment as an answer as the solution?